# in org-mode, how to move point to next checkbox when it's marked completed?

Tags: org-mode, hooks, advice, todo

I work with org-mode checkboxes, marking them as completed as I go.

```
* TODO clean kitchen
- [X] sink
- [ ] stove
- [ ] floors
```

I want org to move point to the next checkbox when when it gets marked `- [X]`

I tried this...

```
(advice-add 'org-toggle-checkbox :after 'org-next-item)
```

...which works when I do <kbd>C-c C-x C-b</kbd>. But how do I make `org-next-item` trigger automatically when point is on a checkbox and I do <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Juancho's assessment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17263/8647) is correct.  As it happens, I've been developing some tools for this kind of surgical advice.  I think this should do the trick:

```el
(defun my/org-checkbox-toggle-advice (orig-fn &rest args)
  "Advice to move to next list item on checkbox toggle."
  (my/with-advice 
      ((#'org-update-checkbox-count-maybe
        :after (lambda ()
                 (ignore-errors (org-next-item)))))
    (apply orig-fn args)))

(advice-add #'org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c   :around #'my/org-checkbox-toggle-advice)
(advice-add #'org-toggle-checkbox :around #'my/org-checkbox-toggle-advice)
```

The hard work here is being done by this macro:

```el
(defmacro my/with-advice (adlist &rest body)
  "Execute BODY with temporary advice in ADLIST.

Each element of ADLIST should be a list of the form
  (SYMBOL WHERE FUNCTION [PROPS])
suitable for passing to `advice-add'.  The BODY is wrapped in an
`unwind-protect' form, so the advice will be removed even in the
event of an error or nonlocal exit."
  (declare (debug ((&rest (&rest form)) body))
           (indent 1))
  `(progn
     ,@(mapcar (lambda (adform)
                 (cons 'advice-add adform))
               adlist)
     (unwind-protect (progn ,@body)
       ,@(mapcar (lambda (adform)
                   `(advice-remove ,(car adform) ,(nth 2 adform)))
                 adlist))))
```

Comment: Awesome it works! One thing. If point is inside the square brackets on the first checkbox, it works perfectly. However, if point is on the hyphen on the first item and I do <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>, it checks ALL the boxes then moves me to the next checkbox.

Comment: I guess my testing wasn't as thorough as I thought it was; nice catch.  It looks like I'm screwing up the prefix arg by using `funcall` instead of `apply` in `my/org-checkbox-toggle-advice`.  Editing solution now.

Comment: Awesome, it works. However, when I do <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> on the last checkbox to mark my last item as complete, I get `Lisp error: (error "On last item")
  signal(error ("On last item"))
  error("On last item")
  org-next-item()
  apply(org-next-item nil)
  org-update-checkbox-count-maybe()`.

Comment: Huh.  I see the message there, but I don't get a full-on backtrace.  What happens when you just call `org-next-item` directly when you're at the last item?  Also, you may want to check your setting for `debug-on-error`.

Comment: After thinking about it a little more, I realized that even if the error just produces a message, it will halt execution of `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c`, and I'm not sure that the call to `org-update-checkbox-count-maybe` will always be the last form to be executed.  So it's probably a good idea to trap those errors in any case, and I'm editing the solution to do so.

Comment: This no longer works, I get `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function (function org-update-checkbox-count-maybe))
  ((function org-update-checkbox-count-maybe) :after (function (lambda nil (condition-case nil (progn (org-next-item)) (error nil)))))
  (progn ((function org-update-checkbox-count-maybe) :after (function (lambda nil (condition-case nil (progn (org-next-item)) (error nil))))) (unwind-protect (progn (apply orig-fn args)) ((function org-update-checkbox-count-maybe) :after (function (lambda nil (condition-case nil (progn (org-next-item)) (error nil)))))))`

Comment: I'm guessing you must have changed something recently that changed one of the functions involved, probably either updating Org mode or adding something new to your config.  It still works for me, and I'm on Org version 9.0 (and Emacs 25.1.1).

Answer (score 2):

The <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> behaviour on checklists is hard-coded deep inside `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c` in file org.el. This is independent from `org-toggle-checkbox` in file org-list.el. So you'll probably have to modify `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c`.

Note that both functions end by calling `org-update-checkbox-count-maybe`, so you could try advising that function instead. But beware that this last function is also called elsewhere.